# Directus error: secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js, directus

I've been developing a Nuxt3 app locally and am using directus as my CMS system (also hosted locally). Everything has been pretty smooth up until now when I started getting this error (full error is below) whenever I tried to log into directus. The strange thing is my Nuxt App can still get data from directus. I didn't change anything about my directus setup and I cant find anything on the internet about it. I've tried restarting directus but that didn't work, I also tried changing the keys in my docker-compose.yml file but that didn't work either (which is no surprise because the keys haven't changed and the error message is new)

Heres the error: 
`[14:48:04.572] ERROR: secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material err: { "type": "Error", "message": "secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material", "stack": Error: secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material at module.exports [as sign]             (/directus/node_modules/.pnpm/jsonwebtoken@9.0.1/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:115:24) at AuthenticationService.login (file:///directus/node_modules/.pnpm/file+api_vue@3.3.4/node_modules/@directus/api/dist/services/authentication.js:148:33) at async file:///directus/node_modules/.pnpm/file+api_vue@3.3.4/node_modules/@directus/api/dist/auth/drivers/local.js:69:56 }`